# syslog-ng make error - iv.h: No such file or directory

Tags: syslog-ng

I am trying to install syslog-ng-3.13.2 from source code on embedded linux. The **./configure** command worked without any error. When I do **make**, I get the following error:

> In file included from /source/lib/cfg-grammar.y:41:0,
>                    from modules/native/native-grammar.y:39: ./lib/logthrdestdrv.h:33:16: fatal error: iv.h: No such file or
>   directory  #include 
>                   ^ compilation terminated. make[2]: *** [modules/native/modules_native_libsyslog_ng_native_connector_a-native-grammar.o]
>   Error 1 make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 make: *** [all] Error 2

Is this because of some package dependency? Which package has iv.h header file?

UPDATE:
As suggested in Stephen's answer I installed libivykis. Now I am getting a different error i.e 
**Makefile:18272: recipe for target 'lib/ivykis/src/libivykis.la' failed.**

The libivykis.la is in /usr/local/lib . I don't know why it is trying to build it in /syslog-ng-3.13.2/lib/ivykis/src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iv.h` comes from [`libivykis`](http://libivykis.sourceforge.net/). You don’t specify which distribution you’re using; on Debian and derivatives you’ll need to install `libivykis-dev`.

Comment: As suggested, I installed libivykis. Now I am getting a different error i.e Makefile:18272: recipe for target 'lib/ivykis/src/libivykis.la' failed. The libivykis.la is in /usr/local/lib . I don't know why it is trying to build it in /syslog-ng-3.13.2/lib/ivykis/src

Comment: Did you run `./configure` again before `make` after installing `libivykis`?

Comment: Yes. I successfully executed ./configure after installing libivykis.

Comment: It [looks like](https://github.com/gcsideal/syslog-ng-debian/blob/debian/unstable/debian/rules) you need to add `--with-ivykis=system` to your `./configure` arguments.

Comment: OK. That error is gone. Now I am getting some libcrypto.a error link fail error.